# ADL fails when invoking function within a lambda

Tags: c++

I'm trying to invoke a function from a lambda that is part of running std::for_each in a specific member function.
Example here:
https://godbolt.org/g/KCBLjL

```
namespace A {
  struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
  };

  void dump(const A::Foo& v) {
      std::cout << v.a << v.b << std::endl;
  }
} // ns A

class B {
public:
   void dump() const {
       (void)std::for_each(std::begin(foo), std::end(foo),
                           [](const A::Foo &f){
                           dump(f); // <- fails here, I expected ADL to kick in
       });
   }
private:
   std::vector<A::Foo> foo = { A::Foo{}, A::Foo{} };
};
```

getting:

```
<source>: In lambda function:
21 : <source>:21:19: error: no matching function for call to 
'B::dump(const A::Foo&)'
         dump(f);
               ^
18 : <source>:18:10: note: candidate: void B::dump() const
         void dump() const {
```

Why does ADL fails here?
I'd assume the compiler would find B::dump but also since A::Foo has dump(const Foo&) in the same namespace, the compiler would add this as an option. But it does not work. Compiled with -std=c++17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[basic.lookup.argdep]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#3), emphasis mine:

> Let *X* be the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup and let *Y* be the lookup set produced by argument dependent lookup (defined as follows).
>   **If *X* contains**
>
> - **a declaration of a class member**, or
> - a block-scope function declaration that is not a using-declaration, or
> - a declaration that is neither a function nor a function template
>
> **then *Y* is empty.**

Answer (score 1):

```
void dump() const {
```

The issue is that you already have a symbol named `dump`() in scope that includes the lambda call, inside this method, here. That takes precedence.

If you name this method `dump2()`, the lookup succeeds as expected.

[The key rule here:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

> ... are looked up in the namespaces of their arguments **in addition to
>   the scopes and namespaces considered by the usual unqualified name
>   lookup**.

Emphasis mine. "In addition to the scopes and namespaces scopes and namespaces considered by the usual unqualified name lookup".

The "usual" unqualified name lookup finds the `dump()` symbol in the calling class. Full stop.